# How can I do variable.endswith("a" or "b" or "c"....) : doAThing in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ends-with

I'm working on a small piece of translation software in its early stages. I'm trying to take the end character of a word and do something with it, but I need to differentiate between different cases.

How can I use `if endswith("a" or "b" or "c") : doAThing`?

I've tried `||`, `|=`, and `or`.

```
if word.endswith("a" , "e" , "i" , "o" , "u") : print("JEFF")
```

Error:

```
 File "test.py", line 50, in <module>
    if word.endswith("a" , "e" , "i" , "o" , "u") and not ("a" , "e" , "i" , "o" , "u"): print("JEFF")
TypeError: endswith() takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the [docs for the 'endswith' function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith), you'll see the function signature. It can take either one string or a *tuple* of strings to match.

The way you are passing in the arguments is as 5 different args. To make those one tuple (and one argument), surround the strings in parenthesis.

```
if word.endswith(("a" , "e" , "i" , "o" , "u")):
    print("JEFF")
```